# Locally Hosted Graphic User HTML Editor for Web Developing

Tags: html, css, text-editor, gui

I'm currently developing a new website for a small business, but I'm the only one that can edit via HTML/CSS/JS files.

My boss doesn't want to rely on CMS for some reason, but wants some sort of GUI HTML Editor implemented within our Apache Server that allows our Designer Team who has no coding experience can edit the dev website.

I proposed services like "Nicepage" editors which has a nice template style editor that can be turned into an HTML/CSS/JS files. However, my boss doesn't want to rely on third-party applications thus wanting the GUI HTML Editor like Nicepage implemented into our local Apache server and host it through that. (So there is no account dependency to the third-party companies like we would if we use Nicepage)

Does anyone know a way to implement this GUI Editor into our hosting network? Like in my head I want it to be something like an admin browser editor that lets you see the dev website in template format when you type in a link like `www.devsite.example/admin`

Anything would help at this point, since I have a general idea like this, but don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: A content management system is a GUI HTML editor implemented within your web server. I think you need to push back on the hesitation to use a CMS.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller took the words out of my mouth.  Maybe ask your boss for some suggestions and they will find it difficult to come up with any.

Answer (score 2):

Between a third-party application and an in house proprietary application; there is the world of open source. So you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

There are things like CKEditor which are the javascript based html editors used by CMS systems. The GUI Editor itself. Can I ask, is that the kind or the interface he wants on the website? It is easier if he understands that when that is implemented it becomes a CMS.

So the question is not CMS or something else it is what kind of CMS? I hope it is not a they write html, which they are not good at and you upload that HTML unto the server CMS that would be a Dilbert content management system, (no offense intended).

### Workflow from Gui Editor to published content?

As Stephen pointed out in the comment. Anything that runs on the site to publish content is called a Content Management System. If you build one from scratch it will still be called a proprietary CMS by everybody else.

If what we are calling a CMS is Wordpress or Drupal, both of them are a bit much for somebody with only design experience. I'm thinking he wants the CKEditor without the complicated back end.

The back end, (what runs on the server), can be PHP or jsnode. Aloha Editor would be a jsnode backend. I'm not familiar with it. Saving the files on the server would for me be quickest using PHP, and then using PHP to embed the content to the pages. A very vanilla but completely functional open source exists which is easy to use to go rouge.

### An example, not a recommendation

My old going rouge CMS has been getsimple. I'm not recommending it but using it as an example. It would take me a lot of hours to build a back end from scratch instead of using what is on the shelf.

In the case of getsimple there is nothing other than php it depends on. The output is saved as XML files. No relative database system build on SQL ... just a flat database design where the HTML is saved in an XML file. So the design team can work in a sandbox either on the same host or their own systems and the XML files are transferred or moved.

The intended workflow, for this example CMS, would be that unpublished content is marked as private, which is the simplest way to allow others to create content without the need to move files, etc. Their mindset is keep it simple; Marking something as private is the simplest sandbox implementation.

This would be the data structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
   <pubDate></pubDate>
   <title><![CDATA[]]></title>
   <url><![CDATA[]]></url>
   <meta><![CDATA[]]></meta>
   <metad><![CDATA[]]></metad>
   <menu><![CDATA[Home]]></menu>
   <menuOrder><![CDATA[1]]></menuOrder>
   <menuStatus><![CDATA[Y]]></menuStatus>
   <template><![CDATA[template.php]]></template>
   <parent><![CDATA[]]></parent>
   <content><![CDATA[]]></content>
   <private><![CDATA[]]></private>
   <author><![CDATA[]]></author>
</item>
```

GUI back end is a minimalist CKEditor but can be expanded or made as complex as needed.

[image]

### Again review open source solutions

To see what you can use so you don't re-invent the wheel. What does your boss want as an editor and where does he want the product produced by the design team to go?

Also what does the design team want?